# How should I interrupt and dispose of a group of threads in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm writing a game engine which performs alhpa-beta search on at a game state, and I'm trying to parallelize it. What I have so far is working at first, and then it seems to slow to a halt. I suspect that this is because I'm not correctly disposing of my threads.

When playing against the computer, the game calls on the getMove() function of a MultiThreadedComputerPlayer object. Here is the code for that method:

```
public void getMove(){
    int n = board.legalMoves.size();
    threadList = new ArrayList<WeightedMultiThread>();
    moveEvals = new HashMap<Tuple, Integer>();

    // Whenever a thread finishes its work at a given depth, it awaits() the other threads
    // When all threads are finished, the move evaluations are updated and the threads continue their work.
    CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(n, new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            for(WeightedMultiThread t : threadList){
                moveEvals.put(t.move, t.eval);
            }
        }
    });

    // Prepare and start the threads
    for (Tuple move : board.legalMoves) {
        MCBoard nextBoard = board.clone();
        nextBoard.move(move);
        threadList.add(new WeightedMultiThread(nextBoard, weights, barrier));
        moveEvals.put(move, 0);
    }
    for (WeightedMultiThread t : threadList) {t.start();}

    // Let the threads run for the maximum amount of time per move
    try {
        Thread.sleep(timePerMove);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {System.out.println(e);}
    for (WeightedMultiThread t : threadList) {
        t.stop();
    }

    // Play the best move
    Integer best = infHolder.MIN;
    Tuple nextMove = board.legalMoves.get(0);
    for (Tuple m : board.legalMoves) {
        if (moveEvals.get(m) > best) {
            best = moveEvals.get(m);
            nextMove = m;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(nextMove + " is the choice of " + name + " given evals:");
    for (WeightedMultiThread t : threadList) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
    board.move(nextMove);
}
```

And here run() method of the threads in question:

```
public void run() {
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(true) {
        int nextEval = alphabeta(0, infHolder.MIN, infHolder.MAX);
        try{barrier.await();} catch (Exception e) {}
        eval = nextEval;
        depth += 1;
    }
}
```

I need to be able to interrupt all the threads when time is up-- how am I supposed to implement this? As of now I'm constantly catching (and ignoring) InterruptedExceptions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thread.stop was deprecated for a reason.  When you interrupt a thread in the middle, the thread doesn't have the chance to properly release resources it was using, and doesn't notify other threads of its completion...something that's very important in multi-threaded apps.  I'm not surprised your performance tanks; I would be willing to bet your memory usage shoots through the roof.  You also don't recycle the threads, you start and stop them without creating new objects, which means whatever broken state the variables were left in is probably still plaguing them.

A better way is to set a flag that tells the thread it should return.  So include in your WeightedMultiThread class a boolean named something like shouldQuit, and set it to false every time start() is called.  Then, instead of while (true) do while (!shouldQuit), and instead of t.stop(), use t.shouldQuit = true.  After you do that to every thread, have another loop that checks each thread for t.isAlive(), and once every thread has returned, go about your business.  You should have much better results that way.

Comment: Don't forget to make the condition variable `volatile`, or protect it with `synchronized` blocks otherwise you could get stale reads and your threads may not terminate correctly. You could also use `Thread.join` rather than `Thread.isAlive`.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like an ideal place to use an `ExecutorService`. You can create `Callable` instances that implement the parallel tasks, submit them to the `ExecutorService`, then use `awaitTermination` to enforce a timeout.

For example:

```
public void getMove() {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(board.legalMoves.size());
    List<Future<Something>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Something>>(board.legalMoves.size());
    for (Tuple move : board.legalMoves) {
        futures.add(service.submit(new WeightedMultiThread(...)));
    }
    service.awaitTermination(timePerMove, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    service.shutdownNow(); // Terminate all still-running jobs
    for (Future<Something> future : futures) {
        if (future.isDone()) {
            Something something = future.get();
            // Add best move logic here
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Replace `Something` with something that encapsulates information about the move that has been evaluated. I'd suggest `Something` be a class that holds the `Tuple` and its associated score. Your `WeightedMultiThread` class can do something like this:

```
class WeightedMultiThread implements Callable<Something> {
    public Something call() {
        // Compute score
        ...
        // Return an appropriate data structure
        return new Something(tuple, score);
    }
}
```

Even better would be to create the `ExecutorService` once and re-use it for each call to `getMove`. Creating threads is expensive, so best to only do it once if you can. If you take this approach then you should not call `shutdownNow`, but instead use the `Future.cancel` method to terminate jobs that have not completed in time. Make sure your `WeightedMultiThread` implementation checks for thread interruption and throws an `InterruptedException`. That's usually a good way to write a long-running task that needs to be interruptible.

EDIT:

Since you're doing a level-by-level exploration of the game space, I'd suggest that you encode that in the `getMove` function rather than in the `Tuple` evaluation code, e.g.

```
public Tuple getMove() {
    ExecutorService service = ...
    Tuple best = null;
    long timeRemaining = MAX_TIME;
    for (int depth = 0; depth < MAX_DEPTH && timeRemaining > 0; ++depth) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        best = evaluateMoves(depth, service, timeRemaining);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        timeRemaining -= (end - start);
    }
    return best;
}

private Tuple evaluateMoves(int depth, ExecutorService service, long timeRemaining) {
    List<Future<Whatever>> futures = service.submit(...); // Create all jobs at this depth
    service.awaitTermination(timeRemaining, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    // Find best move
    ...
    return best;
}
```

That could probably be cleaner, but you get the idea.

Comment: You can in one line of code size executor poll based on number of cores.  Plays nice with the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

The most sensitive way is to use interruption mechanism. `Thread.interrupt()` and `Thread.isInterrupted()` methods. This ensures your message will be delivered to a thread even if it sits inside a blocking call (remember some methods declare throwing `InterruptedException`?)

P.S. It would be useful to read Brian Goetz's ["Java Concurrency in Practice"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) Chapter 7: Cancellation and Shutdown.